# No balloon tip appears when the script is run

Tags: powershell

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms")
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing")
# notify.icon type: Information, Warning or Error.
$notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon
$notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
$notify.visible = $true
$notify.showballoontip(10,"", "The CPU is hot.",[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)
```

When I run the above, only an icon appears in the notification area, but no balloon tip appears. What's wrong with the script? I am using Windows 10 version 1803.

Comment: is there really no closing `)` in your script or did you accidentally mis-copy the script?

Comment: I have corrected the last line of my script.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen `ShowBalloonTip` used in that way. This should work:

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms")
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing")
# notify.icon type: Information, Warning or Error.
$notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon
$notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
$notify.visible = $true
$notify.BalloonTipIcon = "Warning" 
$notify.BalloonTipText = "The CPU is hot." 
$notify.BalloonTipTitle = "Title"
$notify.ShowBalloonTip(1000)
```

Comment: Your script produces the same result as mine does. Only an icon but no tip appears. My script did work properly before I installed cumulative update KB4457128 yesterday, but it does not work now.

Comment: Then I'm not sure. Your updated original code works on my system, which is also Win10 v1803. I have KB4457128 installed.

Comment: I ran "sfc /scannow", which found nothing wrong.

Comment: Is your system showing any other balloon tips? Did balloon tips inadvertently get disabled?

Comment: My system brings up balloon tips every day, but my script cannot do so.